# How can use mysql DATE_SUB in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

How can use mysql date_sub method in laravel? 
In laravel I want to get the value of time property using date_sub.
and I tried the code below but and I can not get anything.

```
$notAllowedTime = DB::table('consultant_timings')
     ->where('id',78,DB::raw('DATE_SUB(time2,INTERVAL 30 MINUTE'));
```

Comment: you are not passing any condition in DATE_SUB.Try my answer by add your DATE_SUB condition with it.

Comment: now tested your code and pass condition,but I have error

Comment: what error you have?

Comment: can I send my code  here,I mean in comment?

Comment: Okay send your code

Comment: okay i am checking but in `whereRaw( DATE_SUB ($time2,'INTERVAL 30 MINUTE'))` what you want to check ?means what you want check here ?

Comment: actually I want to sub 30 minutes of time2 field.I have searched a lot but didn't find a way to do it in php or laravel,finally decided to do this using DATE_SUB method.If now better way I would appreciate

Comment: you want to select `time2 field` with sub 3o min ?

Comment: @BibhudattaSahoo yes I want to this

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **whereRaw** to do this

Try like this

```
$notAllowedTime = DB::table('consultant_timings')
     ->whereRaw('id =78 AND DATE_SUB(time2,INTERVAL 30 MINUTE'));
```

**Modified**:-
According to you description (on comment) you want to retrieve value with sub 30 min
Then you can do like this

```
$notAllowedTime = DB::table('consultant_timings')
    ->select(['*',DB::raw("DATE_SUB($time2,INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) as time2")])
    ->where('id','=',82)
    ->get();
```